# How can I find the number of rows in a table using SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know the total row count of a table to build my page forward/backward system on my site which lists federal bills.  Here is my SQL query.

```
$query="SELECT COUNT (*) FROM bills";
$result = mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$query);
$billcount = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $billcount;
```

dbcxn() is a function I wrote, and I've used it on all of my SQL queries, so I am quite certain that it is not a source of error.

The error displayed on page is the following:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/unipartisan/includes/billvote.inc on line 76
```

I referenced a book on SQL to decide to use SELECT COUNT, but it seems to work differently than I have expected.

Comment: This book must be trash.  I quote, "SELECT COUNT (*) ..."

Comment: All dbcxn does is return a mysqli_connect() so I don't have to do all that typing.  I've used it on all of my queries and it has not been an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to give your count an alias and remove the space after `COUNT`

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM bills";
```

Now you can print it with scope

```
echo $billcount['total'];
```

Comment: This answer is also sufficient.  Thank you for adding the bit about "as total."  That is useful.

Comment: @Unipartisandev you are welcome dude. I think you should accept the question that you think is correct so the question will be completed.

Answer (score 4):

Change to,

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bills"; // No space between COUNT & (*)
```

Always have practice of printing error if any.

```
if (!mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$query)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error(dbcxn('bill')));
}
```

As per @Dave's comment more detail on error can be found *[here](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_15)*.

Comment: Just ran it in my terminal, error when there is a space between functions and the brackets, +1.

Comment: This solved my problem.  The space between COUNT and (\*) made it break.  Also I had to change to echo $billcount['count(\*)']; which is ugly.  So props to Fabio's answer as well for the "as total" addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$yoursqlconnection) or die('query error');
    $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $row;
?>
```

Hop this help

Comment: The problem with this is that you are literally pulling every column of every row from the table and then going through and counting how many you've pulled.  Using COUNT(*) will just pull a number rather than every piece of information from the database.  Point being is it would slow things way down.